# IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to solve the error:

> IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *

def SIR2(I0, beta, gama, w, sigma, p, dt, tmax):
    N = int(tmax / dt) + 1  # nombre de pas de temps
    T = zeros([N + 1, 3])
    T[0, 0] = 1000000 - I0
    T[0, 1] = I0

    for i in range(N + 1):
        T[i + 1, 0] = T[i, 0] - dt * (beta * T[i, 0] * T[i, 1] + p * T[i, 0] - w * T[i, 2])
        T[i + 1, 1] = T[i, 1] + dt * T[i, 1] * (beta * T[i, 0] - gama - sigma)
        T[i + 1, 2] = T[i, 2] + dt * (gama * T[i, 1] + p * T[i, 0] + w * T[i, 2])
        T[i + 1, 3] = sigma * T[i, 1] * dt + T[i, 3]

    return T

beta = 1 / 3000000
gama = 1 / 20

I0 = 10
p = 0
sigma = 5 / 1000
w = 0
dt = 0.05
tmax = 150
T = SIR2(I0, beta, gama, w, sigma, p, dt, tmax)

N = int(tmax / dt) + 1
X = zeros(N + 1)

for i in range(N + 1):
    X[i] = i * dt

plot(X, T[:, 0])
plot(X, T[:, 1])
plot(X, T[:, 2])
plot(X, T[:, 3])

show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Indices of arrays in `numpy` start from `0`. So an array with a second axis of 3, will be *subscriptable* up to a maximum index of 2.

So the following will not work for `T[:,3]`:

```
T=zeros([N+1,3])
```

If you intend to index on 0,1,2 and 3, then you should consider increasing the size of your array, say:

```
T=zeros([N+1,4])
#            ^ subscriptable up to 3
```